# ASP.NET LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I'm developing a user control (ascx) that loads LinkButton objects at runtime. When the aspx page is loaded in the Page_Load, the data source for each LinkButton is an entry of a Dictionary , for example ((ferrari, 2), (chevrolet, 10), (jeep, 6)) randomly ordered. When the user clicks the LinkButton to do PostBack to query the database with additional information about the item. But when the execution reaches the event:

```
protected void objHyperLink_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
```

is no longer the same item that started the invocation of the event, is a different one. How do I get obtain the correct object that starts the event?

Thanks

Comment: If you're assigning the same event to all of the buttons, `sender` should be  the one that initiated the event. You can cast it to `LinkButton` via `DirectCast(sender As LinkButton)` if you need to.

Comment: You should be creating your dynamic controls in the `PreInit` event, not the `Load` event.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ No need for `DirectCast()`. C# can just use it with the `as` syntax. For example `LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;`

Comment: @mason: Wow, I thought for a second I was looking at VB.NET code... I need more coffee!

Comment: The problem is that when the click event for an item triggers such as (fiat, 20), execution returns to the Page_Load and randomly rearranges dictionary. When it reaches the event objHyperLink_Click no longer corresponds to "fiat", but any other, for example (ford, 30)

Comment: If you're doing that work in `Page_Load`, then you should surround it with a check for whether the page is posting back -- `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { /* your work */ }` Then the button assignments will only occur once.

Comment: if surround with `if (Page.IsPostBack!)` then `objHyperLink.Click + = new EventHandler (objHyperLink_Click);` It does not fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comment thread on your question, it sounds like you only want the random assignment to occur once in the page lifecycle and then prevent it from randomizing again before you handle the button click. You can do that by checking whether the page is posting back (which is what happens after you've clicked on one of the buttons and the server is going back through the page lifecycle before it gets to your click handler).

[Icemanind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98094/icemanind) suggested moving this work out of `Page_Load`, which is probably a good idea, but you will still need the same `IsPostBack` check.

```
public void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // create buttons
    }
}

public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The buttons exist, now assign events to them
}
```

I would suggest reading the infamous [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) MSDN article to better understand in which page events you should be performing certain actions.

Using excerpts from the above article, you can see why I used the above methods:

- `PreInit`: "Create or re-create dynamic controls."
- `Init`: "Use this event to read or initialize control properties."